# org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when deployed in JBoss6

Tags: seam, jboss6.x

I have to upload an excel file in a JBossSeam application. I am using poi3.6 jar. The excel upload is successful in application server JBoss5.1. But I got the an exception when I used JBoss6. How could I resolve this problem? Could any please help me to solve this issue?

The stackTrace is as follows :

> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,247 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1) **org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,247 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:61)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,263 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:256)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,263 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:196)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,263 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:179)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,263 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at com.ey.SkillTracker.parseutility.EmployeeUploadExcel.parseXlFile(EmployeeUploadExcel.java:113)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,263 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at com.ey.SkillTracker.bean.administration.EmployeeBean.importEmployeeDetails(EmployeeBean.java:902)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,263 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,278 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,278 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,278 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,278 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,278 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,294 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,294 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,294 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,294 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,294 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,294 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,309 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,309 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at org.jboss.seam.core.SynchronizationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SynchronizationInterceptor.java:32)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,309 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,309 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,309 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,325 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103)
>
> 2011-02-09 10:20:00,325 ERROR [STDERR] (http-10.120.10.19-8086-1)     at com.ey.SkillTracker.bean.administration.EmployeeBean_$$_javassist_seam_18.importEmployeeDetails(EmployeeBean_$$_javassist_seam_18.java)

Comment: Which version of seam are you using?

Comment: I had been using jboss-seam-2.2.0.GA. But now I have replaced seam library files with the jboss-seam-2.2.1.Final version.

Comment: I have tried with poi-3.7 version. But it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?  Change the logging level for poi?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue. I used POI 3.8 and JBoss6.0. The root cause is Classloading conflict between POI lib and JBoss Lib of xmlbeans